# jQuery autocomplete for multiple textboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I am doing a project    using bootstrap backbone  and underscore  where I am using  jQuery auto complete for a text field and it is working perfectly.

Now I encountered  a situation where I have 3 textboxes for first name, last name and middle name.  If I enter any thing in first name I have to  get the  result based on that.

Now if I entered anything  in last name, I need to get the result based on this first name and last name, is there  any way do this type of search using auto complete.

THIS IS MY SAMPLE PAGE:

```
 <div class="row no-padding" style="height:30px;">

            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 af-group1">
                <div class="col-xs-6 af-group2">
                   <input data-toggle="tooltip" id="FIRSTNAME" title="please enter atleast 3 chracters" placeholder="FIRST NAME"  type="text" class="af-input" />
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-6 af-group2">
                 <input id="LAST NAME" placeholder="LASTNAME"  type="text" class="af-input" />
                </div>
            </div>   
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 af-group1">
                <div class="col-xs-6 af-group2">
                    <input id="MNAME" placeholder="MIDDLE TNAME"  type="text" class="af-input" />
                </div>


            </div>
       </div>
```

Now what i really need is that if i type anything in  FIRST NAME then i need to call autocomplete to fetch the result and i am trying to show the result  as a table,now if user type some thing in LAST NAME ,i need to  get the result of persons with first name and last name typed in the the text boxes
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Can you provide your code or a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: As I said in my answer, you can add an "input" event in any field, and in each one put your search code. Input event fires everytime you type a letter in the related input.

Comment: @Genzotto but how can i use actocomplete methond along with this

Comment: @abhi, you can use both events. I have updated my answer to show you how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "input" event to do a search when a field changes:

```
$("#FIRSTNAME").on("input", function() {
    // Your search goes here
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/LN3Qk/)

**UPDATE:**

You can still use autocomplete attaching it to the element you want:

```
$("#FIRSTNAME").autocomplete({
     source: mySourceList
});
```

As seen in: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

Both events can be used at the same time